# How to retain or pull data from last point in Field Maps survey to autofill field in next point?

Tags: arcgis-online, arcade, arcgis-field-maps

I've created a Field Maps form that stores points on a layer. I've been autofilling parcel info for each of these points by pulling attributes from a polygon layer of the parcel map for the county.

Unfortunately, sometimes parcel boundaries do not match up to real world boundaries, and sometimes the parcel data from the county is out of date. In this circumstance, the surveyor needs to manually enter the correct parcel info for each point. This is fine, however can be tedious or time consuming.

I would like to make things easier by allowing the surveyor to manually enter the corrected info once, and have that info retained and autofilled for the duration of the property survey. Does anyone have any suggestions on if this is possible, and if so, how to go about this?

Comment: If you tap on a feature (in an editable layer) in Field Maps, and view it's details, one of the options below all of the details is "Copy". This will create a new feature at the current location (or you can specify another location you specify on the map) that has all the same attributes of the copied feature. Would this be useful for what you need? Of course, you can change some of the attribute values, for the new feature, if you wish.  (This will copy across ALL attribute values, which may not be what you want.)